# how do I clean up /dev/mapper/docker and release space?

Tags: docker

If I do df within my docker container I find a drive mounted on / is 95% full.

/dev/mapper/docker-202:80-131076-9c4e30b5819b23ba61e87d44b3824b780a9f5b8

What is this drive and how do I clean it up?

Answer (score 4):

With recent versions of Docker you can see the space used with:

`docker system df`

and prune it with:

`docker system prune`

The above command combines the **prune** command that exists for volumes, containers, images and networks:

`docker volume prune`

`docker container prune`

`docker image prune`

`docker network prune`

Each command has a `--help` option documenting a `-f` (`--force`) option to avoid asking you questions.  It must be used with care.

-o-

On older versions of Docker I ran the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove dead containers (and their volumes)
docker ps -f status=dead --format '{{ .ID }}' | xargs -r docker rm -v
# Remove dangling volumes
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm
# Remove untagged ("<none>") images
docker images --digests --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}@{{.Digest}}' | sed -rne 's/([^>]):<none>@/\1@/p' | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove dangling images
docker images -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove temporary files
rm -f /var/lib/docker/tmp/*
```

Comment: Thanks but the drive I mentioned was inside the container. So I need to increase that.

Answer (score 0):

OK that is the root of the disk space inside the container. This has a default size of only 10gb

To increase the space there are other answers already posted.